# Problem while authenticating strava from android application

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, strava

I have added this code in manifest file :

```
<data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="strava"/>
```

And then calling implicit intent to do the authorization in strava like this:

```
btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            val intentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "CLIENT_ID")
                .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "code")
                .appendQueryParameter("approval_prompt", "auto")
                .appendQueryParameter("scope", "activity:read_all")
                .build()

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

But getting error in the browser like this:

```
{"message":"Bad Request", "errors":[{"resource":"Application", "field":"redirect_url", "code":"invalid"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at the [official documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/), section `Requesting Access > Mobile Applications > Android`.

You need to specify `redirect_uri` parameter:

```
val intentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize")
        .buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "1234321")
        .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "https://www.yourapp.com")
        .appendQueryParameter("response_type", "code")
        .appendQueryParameter("approval_prompt", "auto")
        .appendQueryParameter("scope", "activity:write,read")
        .build()

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: You can do this with webview in android application, there is no need to use the implicit intent with redirect url. Anyway, thanks for your answer but this is of no help.

Comment: The error you posted is strictly connected to redirect_uri that is a required parameter and even used in Android/iOS examples in Strava documentation. Did you try to set this parameter to the authorization callback domain you set in https://www.strava.com/settings/api (localhost and 127.0.0.1 are white-listed)? you can easily test it in a web browser: https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&scope=activity:read_all; if you remove redirect_uri parameter you get the error message in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the intent filter know that the filter is browsable (can be opened by the app browser, e.g. chrome), which is necessary as you will have to open the app

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="anyappname" android:host="redirect" />
</intent-filter>
```

When creating the intent you need to specify the URI as the one you have in the intent-filter above:

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize")
   .buildUpon()
   // add this redirect uri and change the "anyappname" and "redirect" names as needed
   .appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "anyappname://redirect")
   .build();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Finally ensure you have set an allowed domain name in the strava app settings on your [strava dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K337J.png).

This took me forever to understand so I hope it helps.